# Parsing array of array json and printing in console

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Hi i am trying to make a module which send me the list of objects defined. With in it i am having array of array. So when i print the data i get employees:[object] etc. how do i get into it to retrieve it.

code :

```
var data = [
   {
    projectName: "project1", projectId: 1,
    employees: [
        {fullName: "John Doe", employeeId: 1},
        {fullName: "Jane Smith", employeeId: 2}
    ]
},

    {
       projectName: "project2", projectId: 2,
       employees: [
        {fullName: "John Doe", employeeId: 1},
        {fullName: "Mary Jones", employeeId: 3},
        {fullName: "Bill Evans", employeeId: 4}
    ]
}
];
```

method to return particular object:

```
module.exports.lookupByProjectId = function (pid) {

if( _.where(data, {projectId:pid}))
 {
   return _.where(data, {projectId:pid})
 }

else{

return;
 }

}
```

////////////////////////////////
my output is like:
 {
        projectName: "project2", projectId: 2,
        employees: [
            {object},
            {object},
            {object}
        ]
    }

How do i print the objects too.

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify() to parse object to string.

Comment: how do i search for am employee with id 2 and return all projects. and shortcut. Thanks